# Can you use UIPresentationController for custom presentation/animation styles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle, uipresentationcontroller

I always try to keep my code up to date by using all the advancement and best practices in the API but this time it seams I’m hitting a wall.

I’d like to upgrade some of my code from using View Controller Containment to Presentation Controllers.

The presentation/transition that I’m trying to replicate is one where the presenting view controller’s view partially slides out on the side to reveal the presented view controller’s view.

Unfortunately I’m struggling to figure out the correct setup for the presentation.

The logic choice should be to use `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` for the `modalPresentationStyle` of the presented view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/uimodalpresentationovercurrentcontext

Unfortunately this setting causes

`[transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];`

to return nil in the transition animator, which in return means that I can’t animate the view out of the screen…

Really struggling on this... I’m wondering if the use of UIPresentationController is meant to be used in more restricted scenario and not for highly customised presentations/animations.